# Slow code execution in Electron JS

Tags: javascript, electron

I have started a small project using electron js and leaflet. I draw vector layers on the map. Data of the layers have .topojson format (simplified .geojson).

Displaying layers in electron js is taking very long (up to several seconds). When run in browser (google chrome) same project works very fast. 
I do not know if it is connected, because the engines are the same.

Here is test project https://github.com/oktopuzzz/electronjs-test.

Install, run electron js, open console(F12), click on layers in layers control, check execution time.
Then run server, open browser at http://127.0.0.1:3000, open console click on layers in layers control, check execution time.

The project contains leaflet-topojson.js file, which have a topojson.feature function. This function is performed slowly, but I don't know why.

Please help me.

P.S. sorry for my english